# Intercepting MP3 files access, having issues with avaliability of solutions

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I run a Podcast and because feed and direct links, knowing exactly who is accessing my MP3 files is extremely important. But I'm having issues making my solutions work properly.

Here is what I've tried:

a) PHP and .htaccess
While I was able to write a simple PHP script that served the files back to the visitors with readfile(), I needed (real) byte-range support and it became impossible to use PHP because of the need to open the file on the memory to send the exact chunks visitors requested.

b) x-sendfiles
I don't own the server and while I could try to talk the hosting company into maybe allowing this extension, I simply can't find anything newer than 2013 about it to plead my case, i'm not even sure if x-sendfiles still works. "x-accel-redirect" didn't work too since I don't have root access, and I'm not convinced this would help.

Here is what I think could help, but I have no idea how to implement:

a) .htaccess running a script when the MP3 file is accessed, but only returning the MP3 file to the user.
Maybe similar to cron jobs that only run server-side with no output to user? But I'm not sure how to make .htaccess do this.

b) A newer extension or even configuration? 
Anything about x-sendfiles is almost a decade old, maybe there is something new and I'm just out of the loop?

Thanks for your help! Anything will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you piggyback on say SoundCloud and use their infrastructure + analytics to track your podcasts?

Comment: It's perfectly possible to handle the "byte-range support" using a combination of `fseek()` and `fread()` instead of a simple `readfile()`.

Comment: Not really ERIK, the idea was to keep everything on the server itself, using soundcloud would mean hosting the files on their servers.  

RICK the issue, is not the possibility or not, is that I simply don't have enough memory on the server to load the MP3s files on memory, seek the parts, read the parts, and then send the parts. I've tried and it simply isn't feasible.